# Serialize multiple entries to the same file

Tags: java, serialization

I'm basically making a journal app where each individual journal entry needs to persist, and I would like to keep all entries in a single file.

I've seen tons of tutorials on serializing a single object and so I came up with this solution, *(which doesn't work)* but even if I manage to fix it, it feels like a sloppy solution.

(Here I'm trying to serialize an arraylist, and each time I save an entry, i de-serialize the list and add the new entry to the list before serializing again)

To clarify, my question is: s this a good way to save objects to the same file, on multiple occasions?

Or does anyone have some tips about something else I should try, links to videos or documentation regarding this is also appreciated.

```
public class Serializer 
{   

    //Calls readFile and adds the returned entries to an ArrayList
    //Add the target object to the list and write to the file
    public static void writeToFile(Object target)
    {   
        ArrayList entries = new ArrayList();

        entries = readFile();
        entries.add(target);


        String filename = "entries.bin";

        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = null;

        try 
        {
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            objOut.writeObject(entries);
            objOut.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Reads the file and returns all entries in a list
    public static ArrayList readFile () 
    {
        ArrayList persistedEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        String filename = "entries.bin"; 

        FileInputStream fileIn = null;
        ObjectInputStream objIn= null;
        try
        {
            fileIn = new FileInputStream(filename);
            objIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            persistedEntries = (ArrayList) objIn.readObject();
            objIn.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return persistedEntries;
    }   
}
```

Comment: It might help if you also mention in which way it "does not work" - does it throw an exception? Which one?

Comment: I'm not actually sure what isn't working, because I'm getting a Index out of range exception, and if I've understood ArrayLists that shouldn't be able to happen. But I have only tried to run the program, not the method by itself.

But as you can see my question isn't really about the fact that the code isn't working, I'm just interested to see if the "idea" is good, or if i completely missed something and should head in another direction. :)

Comment: Looking at your code, I notice that you always `read` before `writing` a file.  Have to checked the blank file `entries.bin` case to see what the returned ArrayList object is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a good way to save objects to the same file, on multiple occasions?

I would argue no.  This is because your method `writeToFile` or more accurately `appendToFile` can introduce strange behaviour in edge cases (such as `entries.bin` having an unexpected object).  I would argue for this:

Use `writeToFile(ArrayList<Object> target)` to overwrite the file with the specified array.  Then add a method `appendToFile(Object target)` that handles the process of reading from `entries.bin` from the disk, appending `target` then writing the array to the disk.  This has the advantage of separating any logic related to 'merging' the new object `target` with the file on disk, and the actual logic of writing to the `entries.bin` file.

If just a learning exercise I would go with the above.  Potential [resource](http://crunchify.com/how-to-serialize-deserialize-list-of-objects-in-java-java-serialization-example/)

---

Adding a reformatted version:

```
public class Serializer 
{   
    private String filename;

    // pass in "entries.bin"
    public Serializer(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public void append(Object target) {
        // readfile will return at least empty arraylist
        ArrayList entries = readFile();
        entries.add(target);
        serialize(entries);
    }

    public void serialize(ArrayList entries)
    {   
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = null;
        try 
        {
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            objOut.writeObject(entries);
            objOut.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Reads the file and returns all entries in a list
    public ArrayList deserialize () 
    {
        ArrayList persistedEntries = new ArrayList<>();

        FileInputStream fileIn = null;
        ObjectInputStream objIn = null;
        try
        {
            fileIn = new FileInputStream(filename);
            objIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

            Object result = objIn.readObject();
            if (!(result instanceof ArrayList)) {
                // read object is not an arraylist
            }

            persistedEntries = (ArrayList) objIn.readObject();
            objIn.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return persistedEntries;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why? The second method is entirely equivalent to adding to the list and then calling the first method. Two lines of code.

Comment: By second method do you mean `appendToFile`?  As I said above it is about separating the logic and good coding practices.  With the code he is currently working with the `writeToFile` is handling the following responsibilities: constructing in memory data, reading data from source, syncing source data with in memory data, writing data to source.  Along with all the potential errors and edge cases associated with that.  It makes more sense for him to separate each responsibility into a separate method.